# If condition is not met substitute for values from a row where the condition is met

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, case

HI In my sql I have the following problem 
from a source table similar to the following:

Table1:

```
Employee    Role    Contract Hours  IS primary Role Valid from
1   Role A  35  Y   01/03/2015
1   Role B  35  Y   01/06/2016
1   Role C  0   N   01/07/2016
2   Role A  20  Y   01/01/2016
2   Role B  0   N   01/01/2016
2   Role C  25  Y   01/04/2016
3   Role A  35  Y   01/04/2016
```

So in the example of Employee 1 he started working at a company on March 1st 2015, changed position on 1st of June 2016 and had a second casual role added on 1st July 2017 
I need a query that returns any roles and the most recent Primary role with its contract hours:

```
Employee    Role    Contract Hours  Valid from  Primary Role – Contract Hours
1   Role A  35  01/03/2015  Role A – 35
1   Role B  35  01/06/2016  Role B – 35
1   Role C  0   01/07/2016  Role B – 35
2   Role A  20  01/01/2016  Role A – 20
2   Role B  0   01/01/2016  Role A – 20 
2   Role C  25  01/04/2016  Role C – 25 
3   Role A  35  01/04/2016  Role A – 35
```

The best result I have returns a null value for the additional column if the primary role is N

```
Select 
“Employee”,
“Role”,
“Contract Hours”,
“Valid From”,
 Case
When “Is primary Role” = Y
Then “Role” + ‘-‘ + “Contract Hours”
    Else NULL
 END as “Primary Role – Contract Hours”
```

From Table1

But  instead of the “else Null” I need to find a way to add the most recent Primary value before the Valid from date of any secondary role.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
DROP TABLE T;
CREATE TABLE T (Employee int,   Role varchar(10),    ContractHours  int,  ISprimaryRole char(1), Validfrom date);
insert into t values
(1,   'Role A',  35 , 'Y' ,  '2015-03-01'),
(1,   'Role B',  35 , 'Y' ,  '2016-06-01'),
(1,   'Role C',  0  , 'N' ,  '2016-07-01'),
(2,   'Role A',  20 , 'Y' ,  '2016-01-01'),
(2,   'Role B',  0  , 'N' ,  '2016-01-01'),
(2,   'Role C' , 25 , 'Y' ,  '2016-04-01'),
(3,   'Role A' , 35 , 'Y' ,  '2016-04-01');
*/


select *
from
(
select *,
        (Select max(t1.validfrom) from t t1 where t1.Employee = t.employee and t1.isprimaryrole = 'Y' and t1.Validfrom <= t.validfrom) maxisp
from    t
) s
left outer join t t1 on t1.employee = s.employee and t1.Validfrom = s.maxisp and t1.isprimaryrole = 'Y'
```

result

```
+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+------------+
| Employee | Role   | ContractHours | ISprimaryRole | Validfrom  | maxisp     | Employee | Role   | ContractHours | ISprimaryRole | Validfrom  |
+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+------------+
|        1 | Role A |            35 | Y             | 2015-03-01 | 2015-03-01 |        1 | Role A |            35 | Y             | 2015-03-01 |
|        1 | Role B |            35 | Y             | 2016-06-01 | 2016-06-01 |        1 | Role B |            35 | Y             | 2016-06-01 |
|        1 | Role C |             0 | N             | 2016-07-01 | 2016-06-01 |        1 | Role B |            35 | Y             | 2016-06-01 |
|        2 | Role A |            20 | Y             | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |        2 | Role A |            20 | Y             | 2016-01-01 |
|        2 | Role B |             0 | N             | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |        2 | Role A |            20 | Y             | 2016-01-01 |
|        2 | Role C |            25 | Y             | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-01 |        2 | Role C |            25 | Y             | 2016-04-01 |
|        3 | Role A |            35 | Y             | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-01 |        3 | Role A |            35 | Y             | 2016-04-01 |
+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```